# iOS 10 IMA V3.0 Jams Sometimes on Main Thread

Tags: ios10, google-ima

Using iOS 10 and Google IMA release from 5/9/2016, we are seeing it jamming the main thread sometimes, not the 1-2 secs it claims to take.

The line that is doing this is:

```
  adsLoader = IMAAdsLoader(settings: nil)
```

it locks up the main thread and we are done.

This is not all the time, etc.  We are researching this to try and get more information.

```
#0  0x000000018770e8e8 in __ulock_wait ()
#1  0x0000000100f27320 in _dispatch_ulock_wait ()
#2  0x0000000100f27448 in _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow ()
#3  0x0000000100f0e354 in _dispatch_sync_f_slow ()
#4  0x000000018a165a0c in -[_LSQueryCache cachedQueryResultsForQueries:] ()
#5  0x000000018a16207c in -[_LSQueryContext(Internal) _resolveQueries:cachingStrategy:synchronously:XPCConnection:completionHandler:] ()
#6  0x000000018a161e08 in -[_LSQueryContext(SynchronousResolution) resolveQueries:cachingStrategy:error:] ()
#7  0x000000018a1aa758 in -[_UTTypeQuery resolve] ()
#8  0x000000018a1ba7b8 in UTTypeCopyAllTagsWithClass ()
#9  0x000000018a1ba710 in UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass ()
#10 0x000000018d1e46b0 in WebCore::MIMETypeForImageSourceType(WTF::String const&) ()
#11 0x000000018d1e3eec in WebCore::initializeMIMETypeRegistry() ()
#12 0x000000018dc4afbc in WebCore::MIMETypeRegistry::getPDFMIMETypes() ()
#13 0x0000000191c84c2c in -[WKWebViewContentProviderRegistry init] ()
#14 0x0000000191c84230 in -[WKWebViewConfiguration _contentProviderRegistry] ()
#15 0x0000000191c83b58 in -[WKWebViewConfiguration copyWithZone:] ()
#16 0x0000000191c762f0 in -[WKWebView _initializeWithConfiguration:] ()
#17 0x0000000191c777e4 in -[WKWebView initWithFrame:configuration:] ()
#18 0x00000001003e6c4c in -[IMAWKWebView initWithFrame:] at /Users/sanils/Documents/ios2/google3/googlemac/iPhone/interactivemedia/GoogleIMA3/Display/IMAWebView.m:256
#19 0x00000001003e82c8 in +[IMAWebViewFactory webViewWithFrame:backgroundPlaybackEnabled:] at /Users/sanils/Documents/ios2/google3/googlemac/iPhone/interactivemedia/GoogleIMA3/Display/IMAWebView.m:415
#20 0x00000001003b9ca0 in -[IMAJavascriptBridge initWithSettings:] at /Users/sanils/Documents/ios2/google3/googlemac/iPhone/interactivemedia/GoogleIMA3/Bridge/IMAJavascriptBridge.m:59
#21 0x00000001003c0dd0 in -[IMAAdsLoader initWithSettings:] at /Users/sanils/Documents/ios2/google3/googlemac/iPhone/interactivemedia/GoogleIMA3/Common/IMAAdsLoader.m:119
```